# Installing VCL component in Delphi & C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, components, c++builder, vcl

I created a VCL component in Delphi XE2 and want to install it in entire RAD studio (both Delphi & C++ Builder).

The problem is, if I install the component in Delphi then I get linker error like "*.obj file cannot be found" in C++ Builder. I solve this by manually adding component's LIB file to my project but I would like to avoid that. The only solution I found is to uninstall the component and install it in C++ Builder itself. But, then I have a problem using the component in Delphi...

My component project settings are already set to "Generate all C++ Builder files..".

What to do to have component installed in both IDE's and that they work as intended?

Comment: did you split component to two BPLs, runtime one and designtime one ?

Comment: That seams to solve it! In project options I selected only designetime. Now I selected both and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you have (or are supposed to have) two packages: runtime and design-time.